# How could I better refactor the following code in R using purrr

Tags: r, refactoring, purrr

My function `parse_columns` takes four arguments:

1. A data.frame \ tibble: `df`
2. A character vector representing a subset of the columns in the tibble: `vars`
3. A pattern: `pattern`
4. The name of the new output column to be created in the same tibble: `out_name`

It counts the instances of argument 3 (`pattern`) across argument 2 (`vars`) in input tibble (`df`) and creates a new column (`out_name`) in the tibble.

The function:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

parse_columns <- function(df, vars, pattern, out_name){
  df <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(x = sum(across(all_of(vars), .fns = ~ as.numeric(str_detect(., pattern))
                          )
                   )
           )
  names(df)[names(df) == "x"] <- out_name
  return(df)  
}
```

I invoke the function on (at least) four occasions:

```r
tidy <- parse_columns(tidy, additional_vars, "w", "available_w")
tidy <- parse_columns(tidy, additional_vars, "x", "available_x")
tidy <- parse_columns(tidy, additional_vars, "y", "available_y")
tidy <- parse_columns(tidy, additional_vars, "z", "available_z")
```

My question is, how could I refactor the above 4 lines of code using `purrr` (perhaps using `purrr:pmap()`)?

**EDIT #1**:
Thanks to @NelsonGon's comment on using map2().

I tried the following:

```
library(stringi)
arg1 <- c("w", "x", "y", "z")
arg2 <- "available_" %s+% arg1
tidy %>% map2(arg1, arg2, .f = parse_columns(.,
                                             vars = additional_vars,
                                             pattern = arg1,
                                             out_name = arg2
                                             )
```

But get this error (in the function):

```
Error: Can't convert a `rowwise_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` object to function
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In names(df)[names(df) == "x"] <- out_name :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

**EDIT #2**:
@RonakShah, the tidy df contains PII but the gist is to sum all instances of `pattern` across selected `vars` (row wise) out output the same tibble with `out_name` as a new variable. So using the below:

```
tidy <- tibble(
  a = str_to_lower(LETTERS),
  b = str_to_lower(LETTERS),
  c = str_to_lower(LETTERS),
  d = rnorm(26)
)
additional_vars <- c("a", "b", "c")

tidy <- parse_columns(tidy, additional_vars, "w", "available_w")
tidy <- parse_columns(tidy, additional_vars, "x", "available_x")
tidy <- parse_columns(tidy, additional_vars, "y", "available_y")
tidy <- parse_columns(tidy, additional_vars, "z", "available_z")

print(tail(tidy))

# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Rowwise: 
  a     b     c          d available_w available_x available_y available_z
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 u     u     u      0.692           0           0           0           0
2 v     v     v      1.05            0           0           0           0
3 w     w     w      0.544           3           0           0           0
4 x     x     x     -1.93            0           3           0           0
5 y     y     y      0.943           0           0           3           0
6 z     z     z      0.992           0           0           0           3
```

Comment: `map2` since you change only two variables or base `Map`?

Comment: Thanks @NelsonGon, I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @RonakShah, I've edited the question to provide a synthetic version of tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

parse_columns <- function(df, vars, pattern, out_name){
  df %>% transmute(!!out_name := rowSums(across(all_of(vars), 
                                 .fns = ~ str_detect(., pattern))))
}
cols <- c("w", "x", "y", "z")
result_cols <- paste("available", cols, sep = "_")

tidy %>%
  bind_cols(map2_dfc(cols, result_cols, 
            ~parse_columns(tidy, additional_vars, .x, .y)))

# A tibble: 26 x 8
#   a     b     c           d available_w available_x available_y available_z
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 a     a     a      0.0538           0           0           0           0
# 2 b     b     b      1.61             0           0           0           0
# 3 c     c     c     -0.0172           0           0           0           0
# 4 d     d     d     -0.543            0           0           0           0
# 5 e     e     e      1.98             0           0           0           0
# 6 f     f     f     -1.37             0           0           0           0
# 7 g     g     g      0.425            0           0           0           0
# 8 h     h     h     -0.976            0           0           0           0
# 9 i     i     i      1.19             0           0           0           0
#10 j     j     j      0.441            0           0           0           0
# … with 16 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, just need now to go through and understand why!